# Setting member variable of one instance overwrites another instance's

Tags: objective-c, variable-assignment, instance-variables

I have a question about the following code. The output is wrong: `frac1` should be printing out "2/3", but instead its being overwritten to "3/7". I can't seem to figure out why its being overwritten.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// ---- INTERFACE -----
@interface Fraction : NSObject
-(void) print;
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void) setDenominator: (int) d;
@end


//------implementation section ------
@implementation Fraction
int numerator;
int denominator;


-(void) print{

    NSLog(@"%i/%i", numerator,denominator);
}


-(void) setNumerator:(int)n{

    numerator = n;
}

-(void) setDenominator:(int)d{

    denominator = d;
}

@end


// ---------- EXECUTION--------
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    Fraction * frac1 = [[Fraction alloc]init];
    Fraction * frac2 = [[Fraction alloc]init];

    [frac1 setNumerator:2];
    [frac1 setDenominator:3];

    // set second fraction
   [frac2 setNumerator:3];
   [frac2 setDenominator:7];


    NSLog(@"this is the value of frac1:");
    [frac1 print];


    NSLog(@"this is the value of frac2:");
    [frac2 print];


}
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `numerator` and `denominator` are being set as global variables, not instance variables. To make then instance variables enclose them in {} as part of the @implementation definition.

Fixed:

```
@implementation Fraction {
int numerator;
int denominator;
}
```

Output:

> this is the value of frac1:
>   2/3
>   this is the value of frac2:
>   3/7

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
@interface Fraction : NSObject
@property (assign, nonatomic) int numerator;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int denominator;
- (void)print;
@end

@implementation Fraction

- (void)setNumerator:(int)numerator {
   if (_numerator != numerator) {
      _numerator = numerator;
   }
}

- (void)setDenominator:(int)denominator {
   if (_denominator != denominator) {
      _denominator = denominator;
   }
}

-(void) print{
   NSLog(@"%i/%i", _numerator, _denominator);
}

@end
```

// OUTPUT

```
2015-01-18 18:12:58.844 fraction[29486:2733137] this is the value of frac1:
2015-01-18 18:12:58.845 fraction[29486:2733137] 2/3
2015-01-18 18:12:58.846 fraction[29486:2733137] this is the value of frac2:
2015-01-18 18:12:58.846 fraction[29486:2733137] 3/7
```

In your case int numerator; int denominator; are global vars, not object properties.

Comment: + 1 The critical piece of information that the OP is missing is the last line here, that they were inadvertently using global variables instead of instance variables/properties as they were assuming.

Comment: While this works it is overkill as an answer, the only problem is missing {}.  Additionally the OP may not want `numerator` and `denominator` to be public.